# The 'Postman' icon is not displayed

Tags: 18.04, icons, .desktop

I have a strange problem. I installed Postman following the instructions from the Internet.
Now it can be opened, works fine etc. but icon is not displayed.
occupies a place, shows that it is open and it writes a name when it crosses over it but irritates me because it can not be seen. What is the problem and how can I fix it? I tried to reinstall it and same happened...

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You might want to edit the desktop entry file at `/usr/share/applications/postman.desktop`

Example `postman.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

Also, I learned that they had updated the icon path in the latest releases. So, you can just go ahead and change the path of icon at .desktop file.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, I had the same problem. I solved by changing the icon path to **Icon=/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png**

Comment: This answer isn't valid anymore. I'm working with v7.36.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and still the issue persists.

Comment: @joker Please do add solution for mentioned version if you can. Thanks!

Comment: @JayModi, Couldn't solve the problem! :'( This sucks.

Comment: For 8.5, try `sudo ln -s /snap/postman/current/meta/gui/postman.desktop /usr/share/applications/postman.desktop`

Comment: After creating `postman.desktop` file I started postman via empty tray icon. When postman window launched I could see postman icon in the tray next to empty icon. Then I removed empty icon and attached full-colored icon to tray. Since then this full-colored icon do not disappear after closing postman.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you installed postman. I used snap, the icon (icon.png) can be found in /snap/postman//usr/share/Postman/resources/app/assets.

The folks at postman have refactored their resource tree.